# Extract Urdu strings from XML

Tags: c#, xml

i have an XML file which pretty much looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" enconding ="utf-8"?>
<Hangman>
<string>سال</string>
<string>کل</string>
<string>منٹ</string>
<string>بجے</string>
</Hangman>
```

i want to store its contents to an Array of string

```
string[] words =  XDocument.Load(Hangman.Resources.Urdu)
```

it's showing me an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert System.xml.linq.xdocument to string[]

Comment: "i want to store its contents to an Array of string" -- That doesn't make much sense, a string scalar would, or maybe an array of characters. But an array of strings? What are the elements of that array? [Edit] your question and elaborate. Give an example of the array's contents.

Answer (score 1):

`XDocument.Load` is not going to return you a string array based on your XML, there's no implict conversion between an `XDocument` and a string array; that would involve a lot of assumptions. You need to write the query to tell it how to get that information out of the XML.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(Hangman.Resources.Urdu);
string[] words = xml
            .Descendants("string") // select all elements in the document with the name "string"
            .Select(element => (string)element) // select the value of the element
            .ToArray(); // output as an array
```